# windowId I get from appleScript and CGWindowInfo is different?

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript

I want to  use applescript to get the window of an application, but since the app can have several windows, I use objc to get windowId like follow:

```
    CFArrayRef windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly |
                                                   kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements,
                                                   kCGNullWindowID);
      for (CFIndex i = 0; i < windowListCount; i++) {
        CFDictionaryRef windowInfo = (CFDictionaryRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(windowList, i);
        CGWindowID windowId;
        CFNumberGetValue((CFNumberRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(windowInfo, kCGWindowNumber), kCGWindowIDCFNumberType, &windowId);
      }
```

but this windowId is different from the windowId I get from the appleScript like follow:

```
tell application "/Applications/QQBrowser.app"
repeat with theWindow in windows
    if visible of theWindow is true then
        get id of theWindow
    end if
end repeat
```

end tell

I did not find sth useful, does anybody know why?

my destination is to distinguish the windows of an app, does anybody have some ideas?
Thanks very much~

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Numbers"
    get id of every window whose visible is true
end tell

Result: {1462, 1439}
```

These are unique id's for the open visible windows. You could use this unique id to distinguish windows in an app, and you can also get more information about each window with code like:

```
get properties of window id 1462
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I've tried your method, but the result turns out is different from the CGWindowID, like: the result of appleScript is 93 but the CGWindowID of the window is 7493, so  this not works for me. Finally, I use the method of  judging the bounds of the window to identify the window.